# Use an initial query to merge queries across multiple databases?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017, dataexplorer

Using the *Data Explorer* (SEDE), I would like to find which users have more than 200000 reputation on *Stack Overflow*, and then find details for any accounts they have on other Stack Exchange sites.

Here is the query which provides the list with this threshold:

```
Select id, reputation, accountid
From users
Where reputation > 200000
```

`AccountId` is the key for all Stack Exchange sites.

I have found [this query for aggregating across SEDE databases](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/168067/which-stack-exchange-users-have-the-most-accounts-with-over-200-reputation-all-ac), but how is it possible to do that based on the dynamic results of the previous/baseline query?

Here is the kind of output I'm aiming for:

```
id_so, reputation_so, accounted, other_stackexchange_site_name, reputation_othersite, number_of_answers_other_site, number_of_questions_other_site
1, 250000, 23, serverfault, 500, 5, 1
1, 250000, 23, superuser, 120, 1, 0
2, 300000, 21, serverfault, 300, 3, 2
2, 300000, 21, webmasters, 230, 1, 1
3, 350000, 20, NA, NA, NA, NA
#the case with id 3 has an SO profile with reputation but it has no other profile in other Stack Exchange site
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run non-trivial queries across databases, based on an initial query:

1. Figure out the **common key** in all databases.  In this case it's `AccountId` (which is a user's Stack-Exchange-wide Id).
2. Create your initial query to **feed that key into a temp table**.  In this case:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE #UsersOfInterest (AccountId INT)
   INSERT INTO  #UsersOfInterest  
       SELECT  u.AccountId
       FROM    Users u
       Where   u.Reputation > 200000
   ```
3. Create Another **temp table to hold the final results** (see below).
4. Determine the query, **to run on each site**, that gets the info you want.  EG:

   ```
   SELECT  u.AccountId, u.DisplayName, u.Reputation, u.Id
           , numQst = (SELECT COUNT(q.Id)  FROM Posts q  WHERE q.OwnerUserId = u.Id  AND q.PostTypeId = 1)
           , numAns = (SELECT COUNT(q.Id)  FROM Posts q  WHERE q.OwnerUserId = u.Id  AND q.PostTypeId = 2)
   FROM    Users u
   WHERE   u.AccountId = ##seAccntId##
   ```
5. Use a system query to get the appropriate databases.  For the *Data Explorer* (SEDE), a query of this type:

   ```
   SELECT      name
   FROM        sys.databases
   WHERE       CASE    WHEN state_desc = 'ONLINE'
                       THEN OBJECT_ID (QUOTENAME (name) + '.[dbo].[PostNotices]', 'U')
               END
               IS NOT NULL
   ```
6. **Create a cursor** on the above query and use it to **step through the databases**.
   For each database:

   1. Build a query string that takes the query of step 4 and puts it into the temp table of step 3.
   2. Run the query string using `sp_executesql`.
7. When the cursor is done, perform the final query on the temp table from step 3.

---

Refer to [this other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315533/148310), for a working template for querying all of the Stack Exchange sites.

Putting it all together, results in the following query, **which you can run [live on SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/898901/significant-network-accounts-of-high-reputation-users?MinMasterSiteRep=200000&MinRep=200)**:

```
-- MinMasterSiteRep: User's must have this much rep on whichever site this query is run against
-- MinRep: User's must have this much rep on all other sites

CREATE TABLE #UsersOfInterest (
    AccountId       INT NOT NULL
    , Reputation    INT
    , UserId        INT
    , PRIMARY KEY (AccountId)
)
INSERT INTO  #UsersOfInterest
    SELECT  u.AccountId, u.Reputation, u.Id
    FROM    Users u
    Where   u.Reputation > ##MinMasterSiteRep:INT?200000##

CREATE TABLE #AllSiteResults (
      [Master Rep]          INT
      , [Mstr UsrId]        NVARCHAR(777)
      , AccountId           NVARCHAR(777)
      , [Site name]         NVARCHAR(777)
      , [Username on site]  NVARCHAR(777)
      , [Rep]               INT
      , [# Ans]             INT
      , [# Qst]             INT
)

DECLARE @seDbName       AS NVARCHAR(777)
DECLARE @seSiteURL      AS NVARCHAR(777)
DECLARE @sitePrettyName AS NVARCHAR(777)
DECLARE @seSiteQuery    AS NVARCHAR(max)

DECLARE seSites_crsr CURSOR FOR
WITH dbsAndDomainNames AS (
    SELECT      dbL.dbName
                , STRING_AGG (dbL.domainPieces, '.')    AS siteDomain
    FROM (
        SELECT      TOP 50000   -- Never be that many sites and TOP is needed for order by, below
                    name        AS dbName
                    , value     AS domainPieces
                    , row_number ()  OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS [rowN]
        FROM        sys.databases
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT (name, '.')
        WHERE       CASE    WHEN state_desc = 'ONLINE'
                            THEN OBJECT_ID (QUOTENAME (name) + '.[dbo].[PostNotices]', 'U') -- Pick a table unique to SE data
                    END
                    IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY    dbName, [rowN] DESC
    ) AS dbL
    GROUP BY    dbL.dbName
)
SELECT      REPLACE (REPLACE (dadn.dbName, 'StackExchange.', ''), '.', ' ' )  AS [Site Name]
            , dadn.dbName
            , CASE  -- See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215071
                    WHEN dadn.dbName = 'StackExchange.Mathoverflow.Meta'
                    THEN 'https://meta.mathoverflow.net/'
                    -- Some AVP/Audio/Video/Sound kerfuffle?
                    WHEN dadn.dbName = 'StackExchange.Audio'
                    THEN 'https://video.stackexchange.com/'
                    -- Ditto
                    WHEN dadn.dbName = 'StackExchange.Audio.Meta'
                    THEN 'https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/'
                    -- Normal site
                    ELSE 'https://' + LOWER (siteDomain) + '.com/'
            END AS siteURL
FROM        dbsAndDomainNames dadn
WHERE       (dadn.dbName = 'StackExchange.Meta'  OR  dadn.dbName NOT LIKE '%Meta%')

-- Step through cursor
OPEN    seSites_crsr
FETCH   NEXT FROM seSites_crsr INTO @sitePrettyName, @seDbName, @seSiteURL
WHILE   @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @seSiteQuery = '
        USE [' + @seDbName + ']

        INSERT INTO #AllSiteResults
            SELECT
                        uoi.Reputation                                                                                  AS [Master Rep]
                        , ''site://u/'' + CAST(uoi.UserId AS NVARCHAR(88)) + ''|'' + CAST(uoi.UserId AS NVARCHAR(88))   AS [Mstr UsrId]
                        , [AccountId] = ''https://stackexchange.com/users/'' + CAST(u.AccountId AS NVARCHAR(88)) + ''?tab=accounts|'' + CAST(u.AccountId AS NVARCHAR(88))
                        , ''' + @sitePrettyName + '''                                                                   AS [Site name]
                        , ''' + @seSiteURL + ''' + ''u/'' + CAST(u.Id AS NVARCHAR(88)) + ''|'' + u.DisplayName          AS [Username on site]
                        , u.Reputation                                                                                  AS [Rep]
                        , (SELECT COUNT(q.Id)  FROM Posts q  WHERE q.OwnerUserId = u.Id  AND q.PostTypeId = 2)          AS [# Ans]
                        , (SELECT COUNT(q.Id)  FROM Posts q  WHERE q.OwnerUserId = u.Id  AND q.PostTypeId = 1)          AS [# Qst]
            FROM        #UsersOfInterest uoi
            INNER JOIN  Users u                ON uoi.AccountId = u.AccountId
            WHERE       u.Reputation > ##MinRep:INT?200##
    '
    EXEC sp_executesql @seSiteQuery

    FETCH NEXT FROM seSites_crsr INTO @sitePrettyName, @seDbName, @seSiteURL
END
CLOSE       seSites_crsr
DEALLOCATE  seSites_crsr

SELECT      *
FROM        #AllSiteResults
ORDER BY    [Master Rep] DESC, AccountId, [Rep] DESC
```

It gives results like:

[image: Query output]

-- where the blue values are hyperlinked.

---

Note that a user must have 200 rep on a site for it to be "significant".  That's also the rep needed for the site to be included in the Stack Exchange flair.